# Як правильно оформлювати посилання на статті в журналі Phys. Rev. згідно зі ДСТУ 8302:2015?

Tags: правопис

Як правильно оформлювати посилання на статті в журналі Phys. Rev. згідно з новим стандартом ДСТУ 8302:2015 ? Особливість в тому, що немає глобальної нумерації сторінок, є тільки номер статті, який однозначно її ідентифікує. А сторінки нумеруються в середині статті: 153410-1, 153410-2, 153410-3, ... Також як писати, Iss. (issue, випуск), чи No. (номер випуску) ? Який варіант є правильним?

1) Falkovsky L. A., Pershoguba S.S. Optical far-infrared properties of a graphene monolayer and multilayer.  *Phys. Rev. B.* 2007. Vol. 76, Iss. 15. P. 153410.

2) Falkovsky L. A., Pershoguba S.S. Optical far-infrared properties of a graphene monolayer and multilayer.  *Phys. Rev. B.* 2007. Vol. 76, No. 15. P. 153410.

3) Falkovsky L. A., Pershoguba S.S. Optical far-infrared properties of a graphene monolayer and multilayer.  *Phys. Rev. B.* 2007. Vol. 76, Iss. 15. P. 153410-1--153410-4.

4) Falkovsky L. A., Pershoguba S.S. Optical far-infrared properties of a graphene monolayer and multilayer.  *Phys. Rev. B.* 2007. Vol. 76, Iss. 15. P. 153410(1--4).